# Which memory profiler should I use for ASP.NET Core REST API

Tags: asp.net, profiler, rest, memory-profiling, httpsys

I have a project which is an ASP.NET CORE REST API and the UI is hosted using Http.sys
IIS doesn't come anywhere in picture here. There are multiple backend services created as windows service which include many API calls.
I am looking for a **memory profiler tool** to monitor the performance. Any suggestions will be helpful. I have tried using .NET memory profiler but due to absence of IIS, things are difficult to manage in it.
Can anyone please suggest me a better tool?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MiniProfiler
https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore

MiniProfiler https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ThPz-9XM54

NewRelic also has a profiler (if you are using for development purpose only)

https://newrelic.com/lp/dotnet-monitoring?utm_campaign=Supported-Languages-IND&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_content=SLNT_LP&fiscal_year=FY21&quarter=Q4&gtm=DEV&program=OBSV&ad_type=TXT&geo=APJ&utm_term=%2B.net%20%2Bprofiler&utm_device=c&_bt=501298407481&_bm=b&_bn=g&gclid=CjwKCAjwtJ2FBhAuEiwAIKu19lvqygIsvrOLzUxuZmnd9IcaFRnX5xaMKVEGes5rnV5vhOTWbjb06RoCW0sQAvD_BwE

There is one from JetBrains as well (dotTrace)
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profile_.NET_Core_Application.html

Comment: I tried using dotTrace but it's not helping. The problem here is the hosting mechanism. My UI has been coded differently and is being hosted using http.sys in my project. DotTrace supports IIS and IIS Express. I don't have IIS anywhere in picture.

Comment: Sorry apart from these profilers and the Visual studio inbuilt one i don't know more.

Comment: Actually, you can attach dotTrace to any .NET/.NET Core process (.NET Framework 4.0+, .NET Core 3.0+, .NET 5+) and profile it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profile_Running_Process.html
Hosting mechanism in this case doesn't matter.